# Set the grid to pixelsize in MS Access Visual Formdesigner

Tags: ms-access

How can I setup the Grid (for sanpping) in MS Access in the visual formdesigner to a pixelsize, for example to 25px X 25px?

Answer (score 1):

Access does offer a grid for snapping using the [`Form.GridX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.gridx) and [`Form.GridY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.gridy) properties.

Unfortunately, the *GridX* and *GridY* properties are defined in a very unusual way.

The Access grid uses the measurement unit, as defined in the regional settings, which means if that's set to *US*, the grid is defined in inches, if it's set to *Metric*, the grid is defined in centimetres.

The `GridX` and `GridY` properties define in how many parts that default measurement unit should be subdivided to form the grid.

Access assumes the screen is 96 DPI, so that means setting the properties to 96 would form a 1x1 pixel grid if you're using imperial units. However, only values between 1 and 64 are valid.

The appropriate value for a 25x25 grid would be 3.84 in imperial units, but that's not a valid value. The nearest value would be 4.

Since all control positions in Access are defined in [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip), which are imperial-based, working with the metric system is even more difficult. A value of 2 for both GridX and GridY is the closest you're going to get to a 25x25 pixel grid if you're using the metric system.

There are various calculators to convert pixels to either centimeters or inches, but keep in mind that you can't choose an exact pixel value because of the way the grid is defined.

Comment: To convert Pixel to the metric, you can type in 25px in the visual designer. It is then converted to cm in my case.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't believe there is a "snap to grid" feature in Access. However,</strike> there are alternative approaches.

- You can use Layouts which are grids into which you can put controls
- You can set the Left/top/height/width settings of multiple controls at once
- There are Size/Space and Align settings (which are similar to the option above except a little more automatic)

A combination of these methods can give you a 25x25 grid

Comment: Access does use a grid by default, and moving controls using the keyboard arrow buttons does snap to that grid. Also, when right clicking a moveable control, you can choose _align_ -> _to grid_

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth huh, I guess I've never had a need for that